# Unable to hit the local file in android studio

Tags: android, android-webview

I have created a project on android studio which works fine but when I come to change its local hitting page to my local page which is located in assets floder under the `www` folder, this is location path I try to use the following code:

```
myWebView.loadUrl("../assets/www/Pages/Splashscreen.html");
```

I am unable to hit my local pages. These line of code works fine as

```
myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.facebook.com");
```

why I can not able to hit my local pages which is

```
 myWebView .loadUrl("../assets/www/Pages/Splashscreen.html");
```

where am I wrong ?

Someone please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this `file:///android_asset/Splashscreen.html`

Comment: i tired it, as you mentioned above but still its does not work @shine_joseph anyway Thanks